# Rubocop MutableConstant not observing frozen string literal comment

Tags: ruby, string-literals, rubocop

I'm using RuboCop 0.46.0 and Ruby 2.3.1.

#### .rubocop.yml

```
Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment:
  EnforcedStyle: always
```

#### constant.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

MY_CONSTANT = 'mystring'
```

When run, `rubocop -D` returns this:

```
Inspecting 1 file
C

Offenses:

constant.rb:3:15: C: Style/MutableConstant: Freeze mutable objects assigned to constants.
MY_CONSTANT = 'mystring'
              ^^^^^^^^^^

1 file inspected, 1 offense detected
```

Is there a reason MutableConstant isn't observing my frozen string literal comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every check makes sense for all Ruby versions. Tell RuboCop the Ruby version to check against.

Add the following to your `.rubocop.yml`:

```
AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 2.3
```